# MySQL calculate date diff between two records

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a db table with scan datas:
[scan data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT5yz.png)

I Need the date diff between event= Warenausgang and Event= Wareneingang.
I tried the following code:

```
SELECT i1.teileid, i1.datetime, i1.event, i2.datetime, i2.event, 
datediff(i2.datetime, i1.datetime) as Bearbeitungsdauer
From inventur i1
join inventur i2 on i1.teileid=i2.teileid
Where i1.id>i2.id
And i1.event = Warenausgang
And i2.event = Wareneingang
```

But I get too many results, I want to have only one pair.
Where are the fault?

Comment: You clearly have many events with those names so multiple are going to come up always. You could use LIMIT 1 at the very end of your code to only get one answer, but in reality you should probably figure out more specifically what you want and write more conditions.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)